# select with multiple selection option but in a proper dropdown way

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple city drop down in which I want to use multiple selection option. 
For it I used multiple attribute of select tag but by using it the drop down got converted to a box shaped area with multiple select option. 
What I want is that drop down look should stay as it is i.e. on clicking the select drop down should appear and in it I can use multiple cities with CTRL and whose values then will be used in a php script. 
I have seen multiple jquery scripts for it but I wanted to know if is there some simple way to do this instead of using any jquery or something.
Is there any simpler method to do so???

Answer (score 0):

please try below code:

```
<select id="city" multiple="multiple" name="city[]">
    <option>hawaii</option>
    <option>michigan</option>
    <option>southfield</option>
</select>
```

and you get multiple city value in php

```
echo $_POST['city'];
```

Comment: This is what im doing but by using it drop-down doesn't remain a drop-down but gets converted in to a box with scroll in which multiple options can be selected. I want the drop down look to remain as it is with multiple options

Answer (score 0):

HTML dropdown is made that way, does not allow multiple selections but you can use some jquery plugin like **[this](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/)** for doing that and it is much simpler than creating such plugin yourself.

Answer (score 0):

In principle, the `size=1` attribute in `select` would tell the browser to show just one option, and you could use scripting to change the value of the `size` property to create a dropdown effect. In practice, it mostly does not work.

A more practical approach is to set the height of the `select` element initially and then change the height on mouseover and when focused. Unfortunately browser behavior is not consistent in sizing the element, but the results might be tolerable. Note that the font size in options is reduced by default, so sizing is a bit tricky. In this example I simply set the font size to 100% so that the `em` unit can be used in a simple manner:

```
option { height: 1.3em; font-size: 100%; }
select { height: 1.3em; font-size: 100%;  }
select:hover, select:focus { height: 13em; }
```

The result is a little too small on some browsers and a little too large on some, and IE does not show any arrow to indicate that it’s really a dropdown.